# Spark - Read hidden files from hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am working with pyspark shell to analyze data in hdfs. There are hidden files in hdfs path and I want to read them  through the shell. However the dot files are ignored by the spark. How can I read them?

```
# This is not loading hidden files into data-frame
dir="/abc/xyz"
df=spark.read.text(dir)

# This is not loading hidden files into data-frame
dir="/abc/xyz/*"
df=spark.read.text(dir)

# This is not loading hidden files into data-frame
dir="/abc/xyz/.*"
df=spark.read.text(dir)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses Hadoop APIs to read in data from HDFS. Hadoop input formats have path filter to filter out files starting from "_" and "."
Try setting this property, FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter in your configuration and then use newAPIHadoopFile to create the RDD

Comment: I understood from google that there is some property that needs to be set but i do not find any examples. Would you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your path.

```
  # This is not loading hidden files into data-frame
    # dir="/abc/xyz/.*"
    dir = "hdfs://yourhost:yourport/abc/xyz/"
    df=spark.read.text(dir)
```